# C char* with contents of URL

Tags: c, stream, char

I am working on some homework here, but I have completely run out of ideas. I need to make a simple web browser in C, which must include simple HTML reading. This would be easy normally, but the challenge is this: to challenge myself, I want to use as few libraries as possible. I can use any libraries if I *absolutely have to*.

I need to fill a char* with the contents of a URL in C, but I cannot figure out how I should do it. Any ideas for this?

Please note that this is not a duplicate of similar questions, as I am asking about C, not it's libraries.

Comment: Web browser for homework... are you serious? This is monumental task for one person. To answer your question, make a pointer, use `malloc`, use `strcpy`. But if you can't even do this step, this is definitely out of reach for you now.

Comment: Web browser or web scraper? Fetching HTML or _displaying_ it as a page?

Comment: It is all in text. It is supposed to have simple reading capability, like the `h1` and `p` tags. All it has to do is show the text with different typefaces (which I can do). I can also try to make links work for extra credit.

Comment: Use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html) and don't overcomplicate things.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? from where comes the url? and what use are you gonna do with it?

@Ryan its not overcomplicating. if he knows whats under the hood, then he will have an advantaje whe using the libs

Comment: I told you what I am trying to do. The URL is typed in a text box, and I have to display the downloaded text on the screen. Anyway, libcurl is pretty good for this, and I have it working now. Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear @Justin! :)

Comment: @Jarry: should have pointed Justin at the RFC's - that would've kept him busy ;)

Comment: jajaja nooo not the RFC's as a homework i had to implement an http server. i read the RFC's too many times.
@Justin just use scanf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a rudimentary HTTP client. The following basic actions are necessary:

1. Parsing the URL and extracting the server part and the path part.
2. Connecting to the server with a socket. The socket is your channel that you read from and write to.
3. Writing an HTTP GET request with the path.
4. Reading an HTTP response, which consists of some headers and a body.
5. Parsing headers into meaningful data, such as status, body length, mime type and encoding.
6. Decoding the "chunked" encoding if necessary.

You should be able to start googling now.

Comment: I may just be misunderstanding you here, but this does not look like and answer to my question. I have everything but the HTML loading done; I can pass whatever HTML I want in and it displays, but I cannot load from the web. I am literally minutes from having that does as well. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I'm afraid yes, you are misunderstanding. These 6 points are the very basic and simplified version of web URL content loading. If you want to appreciate a full-featured version, look at a library like libcurl or wget.

Comment: Ok then. I understand now, and I think this is the best answer I have found anywhere. Thanks!